# preparing Headers with redux toolkit and createApi

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Does anyone know how to prepare headers to match a key given by an API? I'm trying to connect to Urban Dictionary API using a key and host name but I'm unsure how to implement that using redux toolkit.

Here's what I have, I know it's very wrong:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { TWord } from "../../types/wordType";

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define",
    prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
      headers.set(
        "X-RapidAPI-Key",
        "<my key>"
      ),
        headers.set(
          "X-RapidAPI-Host",
          "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com"
        );
    },
  }),
  tagTypes: ["Words"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getWord: builder.query({
      query: (word: string) => ({
        url: `/${word}`,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetWordQuery } = apiSlice;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the solution:

The query for getting a word needs to be `/define?term=${word}`, if anyone might need it in the future!

Comment: Won't hurt to escape the word too.